# exact value of $\tan(\tan^{-1}(2/5))$

Tags: functions, inverse

Need help solving the problem $\tan(\tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{5}))$ using inverse functions  without the use of a calculator, I have no idea how to use $\frac{2}{5}$ as I am only familiar with numbers on the unit circle.

Comment: What makes you think it's not $\frac25$?

Comment: What do you know about tan and it's inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what the inverse tangent function is.

In English:

$\tan^{-1} x$ takes an input number $x$ and returns a number (or angle), such that the tangent of that number is $x$. So $\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2}{5} \right)$ will return a number that the $\tan()$ of that number is $\frac{2}{5}$. However, you're putting that number right back into the $\tan$ function ($\tan\left( \tan^{-1} x \right)$). So you're taking the tangent of a number that when input into the tangent function is $\frac{2}{5}$.

In math:

$$y = \tan x \implies x = \tan^{-1} y$$
$$ \tan \left( \tan^{-1} x \right) = x $$
In general, $f\left( f^{-1} (x) \right) = x$

Answer (score 1):

Basically tan$^{-1}(2/5))$ is some angle who's tan value is $2/5$. So, tan(tan$^{-1}(2/5))$ is just $2/5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\tan^{-1}(\tan \theta)=\theta $$ for $\theta \in (-\pi/2 , \pi/2)$